# Can Magento Have multiple stores under one install?

Tags: magento

I want to know whether it is possible to have multiple stores under 1 Magento installations.. which means there will be 3-4 Paypal accounts integrated on my site and each product is integrated to 1 one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. All PayPal module settings have `website` or `store view` configuration scopes.